# Passing variables directly into threaded subroutines

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, openmp, fortran-common-block

I have a textbook example that demonstrates fixing data scoping through parameters. I am wondering why in the code snippet below the author uses a COMMON block to define two variables, **istart** and **iend, ** that are supposed to be private for each thread? Does not the "shared" property of variables with the COMMON attribute conflict with the author's intention to specify **istart** and **iend** as private? Or should we simply remove the common block?

The author says, "We use a common block named bounds containing istart and iend, essentially containing the values used in both the main program and the subroutine." I am wondering if the common attribute will be inherited by the calling subroutine of each thread and interfere the "private" property which **istart** and **iend** are supposed to bear.

Lee

```
program main
    ...
    common /bounds/ istart,iend
    integer :: iarray(10000),N
    N=10000
    ...
!$omp parallel private(iam,nthreads,chunk), &
!$omp& private(istart,iend)
    nthreads=omp_get_num_threads()
    iam = omp_getthread_num()
    chunk=(N+nthreads-1)/nthreads
    istart=iam*chunk+1
    iend=min((iam+1)*chunk,N)
    call work(iarray,istart,iend)
!$omp end parallel
end program main

subroutine work(iarray,istart,iend)
    ...
    integer :: iarray(10000)
    do i=istart,iend 
        iarray(i)=i*i
    endddo
end subroutine work
```

In the other example, the author writes the following code snippet for the same purpose. In this case, I should keep the common block in both the main and subroutine procedures, right?

```
program main
    ...
    common /bounds/ istart, iend
!$omp threadprivate(/bounds/)
    integer iarray(10000)
    N = 10000
!$omp parallel private(iam, nthreads, chunk)
    nthreads = omp_get_num_threads()
    iam = omp_get_thread_num()
    chunk = (N + nthreads – 1)/nthreads
    istart = iam * chunk + 1
    iend = min((iam + 1) * chunk, N)
    call work(iarray)
!$omp end parallel
end program main

subroutine work(iarray)
    ...
    common /bounds/ istart, iend
!$omp threadprivate(/bounds/)
    integer iarray(10000)
    do i = istart, iend
       iarray(i) = i * i
    enddo
end subroutine work
```

If I like to pass the variables **istart** and **iend** in a modern manner, am I correct at making the following revision (which looks a little weird to me because the argument of the threadprivate clause is not the names of common blocks):

```
program main
    use model 
    ...
!$omp threadprivate(istart,iend)
    integer iarray(10000)
    N = 10000
!$omp parallel private(iam, nthreads, chunk)
    nthreads = omp_get_num_threads()
    iam = omp_get_thread_num()
    chunk = (N + nthreads – 1)/nthreads
    istart = iam * chunk + 1
    iend = min((iam + 1) * chunk, N)
    call work(iarray)
!$omp end parallel
end program main

module model       
integer :: istart,iend
contains    
subroutine work(iarray)
    ...
!$omp threadprivate(istart,iend)
    integer iarray(10000)
    do i = istart, iend
       iarray(i) = i * i
    enddo
end subroutine work
end module model
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this more or less the complete example I don't see any place for the common block. No actual sharing happens here, because the values are private to each thread in the `parallel` block and they are passed as dummy arguments.

I would really remove it.

The other case is different. Here the variables are shared using the common block and privatized using `threadprivate`. This is a correct usage, although more modern style is to use module variables the same way.

With modules I would do:

```
module parameters
  integer :: istart,iend
  !$omp threadprivate(istart,iend)
end module

module model
  use parameters
  implicit none
contains    
subroutine work(iarray)
    ...
    integer iarray(10000)
    do i = istart, iend
       iarray(i) = i * i
    enddo
end subroutine work
end module model

program main
    use parameters !not completely necessary here
    use model
    implicit none
    ...
    integer iarray(10000)
    N = 10000
!$omp parallel private(iam, nthreads, chunk)
    nthreads = omp_get_num_threads()
    iam = omp_get_thread_num()
    chunk = (N + nthreads – 1)/nthreads
    istart = iam * chunk + 1
    iend = min((iam + 1) * chunk, N)
    call work(iarray)
!$omp end parallel
end program main
```

Notice the `threadprivate` directive is used only at the declaration of the variables used in it.

Remark, `common` is not an attribute of a variable, it is a separate entity containing the variables. Therefore there is no way the dummy arguments could inherit `common`.

Comment: I have a derived question related to this thread. Please see my post again. Thanks.

Comment: I have extended the answer.

Comment: Please see my revision in the bottom of the original post in response to your suggestion.

Comment: That looks good, only the threadprivate directive should be close to the definition of the variables. Also, the variables can be in a separate module, if more suitable. That depends on the situation.

Comment: Thanks. One more question. Do you mean that, in addition to the one in the main program unit, I need to put the other !$omp threadprivate(istart,iend) right after the variable declaration area of "istart" and "iend" in the module "model", rather than in the local procedure---subroutine "work"?

Comment: Excellent! The new example exactly demonstrates the techniques which my real project needs.